# Writing a JVM bytecode program to calculate and print the first 20 numbers in a fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, bytecode

This is my code for a bytecode program to calculate the first 20 numbers of the fibonacci sequence only being able to use iconst_1.

```
iconst_1    
istore_1    
iconst_1    
istore_2    
iconst_1    
istore_3    
getstatic #2    
iconst_1    
invokevirtual #3    
getstatic #2    
iconst_1
invokevirtual #3    
iconst_1    
istore_4    
iload_4    
bipush 18    
if_icmpgt 51    
iload_1    
iload_2    
iadd    
istore_3    
getstatic #2    
iload_3    
invokevirtual #3    
iload_2    
istore_1    
iload_3    
istore_2    
iinc 4,1    
goto 23    
return
```

Now my main issue is that it is in the form of a file called fibonacci.bc and I need to compile it and run it to make sure it works. Are there any issues I need to address in the program first such as syntax and such. How would I go about doing that on the JVM?

Comment: In order to paste code in your question you need to prepend four spaces before each code line or use "code" button in toolbar.

Comment: You are looking for an _assembler_ for Java bytecode. That should get your search started.

Comment: Note that, like with ordinary Java source code, you need to specify a class around the executable code, including a method that hosts the code.

Comment: Also a constant pool content must be specified. Otherwise `invokevirtual #3` and `getstatic #2` are quite meaningless. Also note that you have to specify a constructor for your class. Otherwise it will not pass the verification.

Answer (score 1):

An easy option is to use [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/). You'll need to learn its syntax. It's pretty straightforward though.

This is your what you code will look like in Jasmin (note the use of `label`, `inc`, `istore 4`, `iload 4`):

```
.class public Fib
.super java/lang/Object

.method private static fib()V
  .limit stack 2
  .limit locals 5

  iconst_1
  istore_1
  iconst_1
  istore_2
  iconst_1
  istore_3
  getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  iconst_1
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
  getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  iconst_1
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
  iconst_1
  istore 4
label23:
  iload 4
  bipush 18
  if_icmpgt label51
  iload_1
  iload_2
  iadd
  istore_3
  getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  iload_3
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
  iload_2
  istore_1
  iload_3
  istore_2
  iinc 4 1
  goto label23
label51:
  return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 0
  .limit locals 1

  invokestatic Fib/fib()V
  return
.end method
```

Saving your file in e.g. `fib.j` and running `java -jar jasmin.jar fib.j` will give you `Fib.class`.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, good.

In java (8):

```
public class Fibonacci {
        public static long fib(int n) {
            if (n <= 1) return n;
            else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int N = 20;
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
        }
}
```

After compiling, disassemble with:

```
javap -c Fibonacci.class
```

Which produce:

```
  public static long fib(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iconst_1
       2: if_icmpgt     8
       5: iload_0
       6: i2l
       7: lreturn
       8: iload_0
       9: iconst_1
      10: isub
      11: invokestatic  #2                  // Method fib:(I)J
      14: iload_0
      15: iconst_2
      16: isub
      17: invokestatic  #2                  // Method fib:(I)J
      20: ladd
      21: lreturn

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        20
       2: istore_1
       3: iconst_1
       4: istore_2
       5: iload_2
       6: iload_1
       7: if_icmpgt     48
      10: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      13: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      16: dup
      17: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      20: iload_2
      21: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      24: ldc           #7                  // String :
      26: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      29: iload_2
      30: invokestatic  #2                  // Method fib:(I)J
      33: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(J)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      36: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      39: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      42: iinc          2, 1
      45: goto          5
      48: return
}
```

I guess the exercice is to write the code directly in bytecode, and not to decompile a java version of your problem, but if it can help, good :)